# How to get jquery Tooltipster Plugin to work for newly created DOM elements?

Tags: jquery, dom, tooltipster

I'm using the Tooltipster plugin http://calebjacob.com/tooltipster/ which is great but I have dynamically generated content that's being inserted into the DOM. It doesn't seem like tooltipster is detecting those as it's being set to trigger on Document Ready.

I know this is a bit of an esoteric plugin but any ideas on how to get the plugin to work for newly created elements in the DOM?

Thanks

Comment: I have also the same issue.Did any one get a solution for that?

Answer (score 3):

Try this one

`$(document).on('mouseover', '.ololo', function(event) {
$(this).tooltipster({multiple:true});
});`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the instantiation script in the ajax content too.

Also set the option "multiple:true"

Its worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be accomplished if you write you plugin load code after the DOM has finished loading. You may write inside:

```
$(window).load(function()

});
```

As this executes after all DOM has finished loading.