# Tooltipster not working in a ajax content

Tags: tooltipster

While searching in stack overflow .I find an old issue that i am facing too.But no one answered it.
So just wants to know anyone have any idea about it

[How to get jquery Tooltipster Plugin to work for newly created DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19187895/how-to-get-jquery-tooltipster-plugin-to-work-for-newly-created-dom-elements)

Following is my code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.test_link').tooltipster({
    interactive:true,   
    content: 'Loading...',
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
        continueTooltip();      
        // next, we want to check if our data has already been cached
        //if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'example.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    // update our tooltip content with our returned data and cache it
                    origin.tooltipster('content', $(data)).data('ajax', 'cached');
                }
            });
      //  }
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 3):

My problem solved.

Just add the instantiation script in  the ajax content too.
also set the option multiple:true

ie

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.test_link').tooltipster({
    interactive:true, 
    multiple:true,
    content: 'Loading...',
    functionBefore: function(origin, continueTooltip) {
        continueTooltip();      
        // next, we want to check if our data has already been cached
        //if (origin.data('ajax') !== 'cached') {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'example.php',
                success: function(data) {
                    // update our tooltip content with our returned data and cache it
                    origin.tooltipster('content', $(data)).data('ajax', 'cached');
                }
            });
      //  }
    }
});

});
```

It worked for me in Firefox.But didn't tested in other browser

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, and the problem was solved, but i recently needed something similar.

Adding the initialization on every ajax function was not a solution since we had several content dynamically loaded on the page, so the simplest solution found was:

```
$(document).on('mouseenter', '[data-toggle="tooltip"]', function(){
        if ($(this).is('.tooltipstered')) {
            // Do nothing
        } else {
            $(this).tooltipster({
                delay: 50,
                // Your other Tooltipster options
            });
            $(this).mouseover();
        }
});
```

`$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]')` being the OP's `$('.test_link')`.

The `if` deter the repeated initialization of document `mouseenter`.